# Google tracker identification

Tags: java

I've noticed that sites that use Google's recaptcha have the tracker sb_wiz.zpc.gws-wiz-serp dropped locally. This tracker seems to be associated with Google services. However, I can't find any information on its purpose or the data it collects from users. Can you help?

After removing recaptcha from a site, we no longer see this tracker. However, some data has been collected and we would like to know for what purpose.

Comment: Is this java a specific question or a browser topic in general? Anyways interesting question

Comment: Indeed, I had no more precise choice than to put the Java tag. But my question is generally about web browsers and tracers.